# Machine learning algorithm - Boosting, number of interaction depth, d

Tags: machine-learning

I am learning boosting algorithm. I have been thinking of why small number of interaction depth works better than larger number? And how do people usually choose the number of interaction depth to be used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean interaction depth in trees. (R)

Overfitting can be your problem.

You will adapt to much on your training data which is only assumed to give a full image of your test data.

Think of it like fitting a polynomial to a set of points and afterwards you add unknown points. The higher your order of the polynomial the better you can fit your known data (more or less) but this may result in a peaky function. 
If you add new points it is likely that they are not covered by your function.

Comment: Yes i mean interaction depth, do you have example in pictures so that I can imagine what you mean? Thank you!

Comment: Look at the results of this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66543/random-forest-is-overfitting. You have great training accuracy but low testing accuracy. This means your classifier has been adapted to your training data. If you now apply your classifier on unseen data, this data can have a other shape then the one you have trained your classfier. The descission boundary will still be the same which indicates the poor results in testing. Optical example and detailed description here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting

Comment: May I ask when interaction depth=1, people say usually it works well? how does the tree look like when depth=1? One straight line? If yes, how the decision rule works in this case?

Comment: Take a look at the slides here: https://www.slideshare.net/glouppe/understanding-random-forests-from-theory-to-practice

Comment: You will see that depth one means linear db. Dont know with what problem you are dealing but I doubt that depth = 1 is sufficient for pattern recognition in most cases. Are they talking about Trees or Forests?

Comment: Boosting trees.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you mean with boosting.

Comment: Normally boosting combines different low level classifiers like viola and jones which I would interpret as a random forrest

Comment: this is function i am using actually in R, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf. Interaction depth is the parameter i am referring to.

Comment: Here you can verify my answer: 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/what-does-interaction-depth-mean-in-gbm